# Сортировка строк

Tags: строки, c++, visual-c++

Помогите, пожалуйста с заданием: запросить у пользователя количество студентов, ввести их фамилии в произвольном порядке и разбить их на две равные группы так, чтобы однофамильцы обязательно оказались в разных группах.

Как сделать, чтобы однофамильцы оказались в разных группах?

Comment: А если трое Ивановых, тогда как?

Answer (score 1):

Делаете 2 списка (группа 1 и группа 2).  **Перед** включением студента в группу просматриваете списки и подсчитываете число однофамильцев в каждом. Включаете его в  группу, где однофамильцев меньше. В случае равенства в ту, которая меньше.

Comment: 1. Число студентов должно быть чётным. 2. Однофамильцев не должно быть больше двух. Отсортировать по фамилиям. Нечётных -- в одну группу, чётных -- во вторую.

Answer (score 0):

Целесообразнее реализовать через массивы.
p.s. Условие задачи неполное, допустим, кол-во студентов нечётное, количество однофамильцев больше двух.